# Do booster packs continue to drop once I crafted badge?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I've obtained all the "default" drops, got some booster later and finally crafted a badge. Will I continue to get more boosters for the SAME game that I already crafted badge for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

Booster packs will always have a chance to drop even after crafting **any or all** levels of your badge. Note that they will not start to drop until all your cards have been unlocked for that game.

From the [FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq):

> Once you have received all of your card drops, you become eligible for a booster pack, which is a set of 3 trading cards that may include both basic and foil cards. Booster packs are granted randomly to eligible users as more badges are crafted by members of the community. Make sure you log in to Steam each week to maintain eligibility.

Also note that your chance of receiving a drop increases with your Steam level, so in fact crafting more badges (and leveling up every 10 levels) will further increase your chance of receiving a drop.

> Once eligible, your Steam Level increases your rate of receiving a booster pack drop:
>
> - Level 10: +20% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 20: +40% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 30: +60% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 40: +80% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 50: +100% increase in your drop rate (i.e. the rate has doubled)
> - Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can continue to get booster packs for games you've made the badge for.  There are multiple levels of badge you can craft (5 normal + 1 foil), so if you get another booster, you may want to keep it and try for the next level of badge.

Comment: Will they drop even after I crafted ALL existing levels?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov From what I can tell, yes.  I'm pretty sure I've gotten TF2 boosters despite having a level 5 TF2 badge.